# Access Dynamic Panel on button click event

Tags: vb.net, button, dynamic, panel

I have few pannels and button created dynamically now I need to access panel on button click event.

This is how i am creating dynamic button and Pannel

```
   While rst.Read()
        Dim panel As New Panel
        Dim panel1 As New Panel
        Dim mylink As New LinkLabel
        Dim btn As New Button
        Dim Tooltip As New ToolTip()
        Tooltip.SetToolTip(mylink, rst!form_name)
        mylink.Name = rst!form_name
        AddHandler mylink.Click, AddressOf HandleDynamicLinkLabelClick
        AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf HandleDynamicButtonClick
        mylink.Dock = DockStyle.Left
        btn.Name = rst!form_name
        btn.Tag = rst!form_name
        panel1.Tag = rst!form_name
        btn.Text = "<"
        panel.Controls.Add(mylink)
        panel.Controls.Add(btn)
        panel1.Name = rst!form_name
        panel1.Controls.Add(lbl)

        Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panel)
        Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panel1)

    End While
    rst.Close()
```

This is the code for dynamic button click event here i need to access pannel1 from the above procedure

```
 Private Sub HandleDynamicButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)

    End Sub
```

Comment: you can get it by  dim panel =DirectCast(FlowLayoutPanel1.Control("panel1"),Panel)

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to actively 'know' what the names of your dynamically created controls are so try something like this:

```
   Private Name1 As String
Private Name2 As String


while rst.read
    Dim panel As New Panel
    Dim panel1 As New Panel
    Dim mylink As New LinkLabel
    Dim btn As New Button
    Dim Tooltip As New ToolTip()
    Tooltip.SetToolTip(mylink, rst!form_name)
    mylink.Name = rst!form_name
    AddHandler mylink.Click, AddressOf HandleDynamicLinkLabelClick
    AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf HandleDynamicButtonClick
    mylink.Dock = DockStyle.Left
    Name1 = cstr(rst!form_name)
    btn.Name = Name1
    btn.Tag = rst!form_name
    panel1.Tag = rst!form_name
    btn.Text = "<"
    panel.Controls.Add(mylink)
    panel.Controls.Add(btn)
    Name2 = Cstr(rst!form_name)
    panel1.Name = Name2
    panel1.Controls.Add(lbl)

    Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panel)
    Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panel1)
end while


Private Sub HandleDynamicButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Select Case btn.Name
        Case Name1
            'do something here
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already storing "rst!form_name" in the Name of the Button:

```
btn.Name = rst!form_name
```

So why not store the Panel in the Tag instead?

```
btn.Tag = panel1
```

Then you can retrieve it in your handler:

```
Private Sub HandleDynamicButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim panel1 As Panel = DirectCast(btn.Tag, Panel)
    ' ... use "panel1" somehow ...
End Sub
```